# WPF: How do ResourceKeys in key syntax work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found this in use of devexpress grid. I'm wondering how this syntax works that specified in the key.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{dxgt:GridColumnHeaderThemeKey ResourceKey=HeadersVerticalLineBrush}" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

I'm used to

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which part is confusing you? The namespace syntax or the key reference?

Answer (score 1):

Keys can be any object, including strings. There is also a special type of key called a [ComponentResourceKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.componentresourcekey.aspx), which allows you to access resources that may be in another assembly. As the ComponentResourceKey stores the name of the resource, as well as the assembly in which it is stored.

GridColumnHeaderThemeKey probably returns a ComponentResourceKey with the assembly information already filled out. Alternatively, it could extend the [ComponentResourceKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753186.aspx) or [Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.staticextension.aspx) markup extensions to make it easier to reuse it's resources.

If you open it up in Reflector, then you should be able to determine exactly what it does.

Just to clarify, the GridColumnHeaderThemeKey is a [custom markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx), as explained [here](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2008/12/creating-custom-wpf-markup-extension-to.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `SolidColorBrush` is being set to the colour (black) which colours the columns of the grid by using a specific data grid brush `HorizontalGridLinesBrush` which sets the brush applied to the horizontal lines.

For example, set the grid lines to red.

`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{dxg:GridColumnHeaderThemeKey                         ResourceKey=HeadersVerticalLineBrush}" Color="Red"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{dxg:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=GridDataRowDelimiterBrush}" Color="Red"/>`

This link describes the different brush styles you can use.
[DataGrid Brushes](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/C1DataGridSL/default.htm?turl=c1datagridbrushes.htm)